# UnicodeDecodeError in python input function runned by XFCE Terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, encode, xfce

In a loop, I add input function and type Persian (like Arabic) characters. It works well, but sometimes I get errors like this:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 6: invalid continuation byte`
I Use Debian and Run my code in xfce terminal and the default encode is utf-8.

I tried this instead of input():
`sys.stdin.readline()`

But, that error occurs. Is it a xfce Terminal Problem or a Python problem? Why does it occur sometimes? After get this error, I run my code again and type exactly same string, and this time, everything works well.

Can I handle it by this:

```
while True:
 try:
     i = input()
     break
 except:
     pass
```

Or should I do something else?

---

Extra information:
My inputs are Persian number like '۰ ۱ ۴' and English (for my purpose, it not important). Sometimes I amend a text that is a book name like 'دیوان حافظ ۳ جلدی'
In my XFCE Terminal default encode is utf-8. Is it possible when I get this error, Terminal used another encode?

---

I guess this is a XFCE terminal bug. I installed terminator and used it for a while. That error never occurred, But I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and make it a [mcve]? What Persian text do you enter to trigger the behavior?